# UI update not working for urlSession downloadTask didWriteData

Tags: swift, user-interface, dispatch, urlsession

Currently, I've got a problem with the update of the user interface when using a download task. The following function should update the user interface, but it works just sometimes. Why doesn't it work every time I download a file? The log of `NSLog` is shown in the debugger every time!

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
  let curDownloadSize = totalBytesWritten / (1024*1024)
  let totalDownloadSize = totalBytesExpectedToWrite / (1024*1024)

  if curDownloadSize != oldDownloadSize {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.progressLabel!.text = "\(self.curDownloadSize)MB / \(self.totalDownloadSize)MB"
      self.progressView!.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
      NSLog("Download progress: \(Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))");
    }
  }
}
```

`progressLabel` and `progressView` are both available at this time.

BTW, I have tested it with the same file multiple times and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

**Update:** I read about using a second dispatch queue like this

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    (same as above)
  }
}
```

but this is also working just sometimes.

Comment: You don't need to use DispatchQueue at all inside that method

Comment: Ok, I tried it before with the same result, except, that I believe, that it doesn't work as often as with the DispatchQueue.

Comment: are you doing multiple downloads simultaneously? You only have one label. Make sure you cancel any prior session task before  starting a new one.

Comment: Again that method it is already called / executed in the main thread. Do not use dispatch there

Comment: No multiple downloads. And again, also without the dispatch, there is the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I solved the problem.

The problem occurs if too many events are pushed to the main queue. It just occurred with a very good internet connection. In this case the callback has been called too often.

My solution:

```
progressCounter += 1
if progressCounter % 30 == 0 {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.progressLabel!.text = "\(self.curDownloadSize)MB / \(self.totalDownloadSize)MB"
    self.progressView!.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    NSLog("Download progress: \(Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))");
  }
}
```

The `progressCounter` has been initialized to 0 before.